# How to add minWidth and maxWidth for columns in antdesign table

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, html-table, ant-design-pro

I want to add maxWidth and minWidth in columns of antdesign table

Please refer this example

https://codesandbox.io/s/k870nt?file=/demo.tsx

Answer (score 0):

you can style targeting the `colgroup` of the `table`, you can see the dev tools image for an idea I did for one of the columns

[image: Edit Basic Usage - antd@4.24.1 (forked)]

[image]

Comment: Can you do changes in code, and add saved link here

Comment: edited and added, just the change in `index.css` file ..

Comment: I am unable to see anything in index.css file

Comment: I just literally added this small snippet `colgroup {min-width: 145px;}`  ... you can try adding it and see...

Comment: this works for 1st column, how we will do for all columns

Comment: I saw the docs but couldn't see any e.g.'s on it and customising would be difficult I guess ..... I would rather use [TanStack's table](https://tanstack.com/table/v8/docs/examples/react/column-sizing)  or you have to integrate [something as so](https://codesandbox.io/s/xquvoz)